# How to send a file in ActiveJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I send a big **.csv** for processing. The file is processed for a long time and I want to put this task in background.

Error: **ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: File)**

Documentation says:

> Raised when an unsupported argument type is set as a job argument. We
>   currently support NilClass, Integer, Fixnum, Float, String, TrueClass,
>   FalseClass, Bignum, BigDecimal, and objects that can be represented as
>   GlobalIDs (ex: Active Record). Raised if you set the key for a Hash
>   something else than a string or a symbol. Also raised when trying to
>   serialize an object which can't be identified with a Global ID - such
>   as an unpersisted Active Record model.

I want to know is there any way for this purpose?

Use Carrierwave

My service object:

```
class ImportPrice
  attr_accessor :file, :filename

  def initialize(file, filename)
    @file = file
    @filename = filename
  end

  def call
    ImportPriceJob.delay_later(@file, @filename)
  end
end
```

my job:

```
class ImportPriceJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(file, filename)
    region = Region.find_or_create_by(name: filename)

    Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file).each do |i|
      item = Item.where(oem: i[2]).first

      if item.present?
        item.update_attributes(weight: i[7].to_f)
        # Обновлять только в том случае, если атрибуты изменились
        price = Pricelist.create_with(name: filename).find_or_create_by(region_id: region.id)
        price_item = ItemPrice.create_with(pricelist_id: price.id).find_or_create_by(item_id: item.id)
        price_item.update_attributes(qnt: i[5], cost: i[3].to_i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know is there any way for this purpose?

The purpose of this is a serialization process, the @file here is a ruby object an instance of the File class, you can't serialize the ruby object(to be honest, you can, but not in this case), you should pass a simple types.
Dont pass a whole file to `ImportPriceJob.delay_later(...)`, send just a path as string.

```
def call
  path_to_file = @file.path # for example
  ImportPriceJob.delay_later(path_to_file, @filename)
end
```

Then open a file in your delayed job, [`Roo::Spreadsheet.open`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roo/Roo/Spreadsheet.open) method accept a path to the file as an argument:

```
class ImportPriceJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(path_to_file, filename)
    region = Region.find_or_create_by(name: filename)

    Roo::Spreadsheet.open(path_to_file).each do |i|
    # some code here
```